# Smart Contract Working in Remix Testnet but Reverting Transactions in DApp with Metamask

Tags: web3js, remix, javascript

**Question:**
I'm encountering a perplexing issue with my smart contract that's causing transactions to be reverted when interacting with it through a DApp using web3.js and Metamask. Strangely, the same contract functions work flawlessly when tested on Remix using a testnet environment. I'm seeking guidance on how to troubleshoot this discrepancy.

**Issue:**
When using the smart contract's functions on Remix's testnet environment, everything runs smoothly, and transactions are executed successfully. However, when I integrate the contract into a DApp and interact with it using web3.js and Metamask, I'm consistently encountering the following error message:

```
Transaction has been reverted by the EVM: {"type":"2", ... }
```

**Details:**
The smart contract includes functions for minting NFTs and related operations.
I've tried adjusting gas values to ensure sufficient gas is provided for execution.
I've verified that the Metamask wallet is unlocked, active, and connected to the correct network.
The gas estimation for transactions appears to be accurate, but transactions are still being reverted.
There haven't been any changes to the smart contract code between the Remix tests and the DApp integration

**Request for Assistance:**
I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or steps that the Ethereum community can provide to help me troubleshoot this issue. If you've encountered similar situations or have expertise in smart contract development and DApp integration, your input would be invaluable.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

BscScan Contract address: 0x1c12c36a805d57b8356d9a07dd06c59cc658eaed

Snip of contract code on remix:

```
contract TESTCONTRACT is ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, Ownable  {

uint public weiPixelPrice = 1000000 * (10 ** 18); /* Price in PEPE */
address contractOwner;

constructor(address _contractOwner) ERC721("Testorr", "TEST") {
    contractOwner = _contractOwner;
}

/// changes the cost of minting
function setCost(uint newCost) public {
    require(contractOwner == msg.sender, "Not contract owner!");
    weiPixelPrice = newCost;
}
}
```

Javascript front end:

```
const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
contract = web3.eth.Contract(ABI,0x1c12c36a805d57b8356d9a07dd06c59cc658eaed)

tx = await contract.methods.setCost("whatever new value").send({ from: accounts[0]});
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be a problem with the latest release, method`.call()` works fine but `.send()` not working.

**Solution:**
downgrade to use web3@4.0.3 instead of web3@latest that'll be a temporary fix while the mods in web3js discord investigate.

meanwhile, im using ether js to replace web3js. its working ok for me now.